# Vista stuck on windows update 3 of 3

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

Vista x32 ultimate stuck on window update 3 of 3 - keeps rebooting.

Dont have the os disk to hand to repair, safemode - all 3 dont work.

Advanced options - last known config - doesnt work either

Any suggestions

Comment: Have you unplugged all cables and devices from the computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me: I did not have an OS disc available.

BE AWARE – Manually changing system files is highly risky – exhaust all other avenues first.

From link
http://www.tipandtrick.net/2008/endless-reboot-loop-while-configuring-updates-stage-3-of-3-during-vista-sp1-installation/

I could see a possible solution was to delete or rename the file C:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml

When I tried by going into System Repair and choosing the command prompt boot option it appeared to let me rename this file to something else – but in the background Vista had not changed the file for the system as a whole - only for my user login.

Therefore I connected the hard disc from the ailing computer into a working Vista PC.
I booted up the working PC – and was then able to follow the instructions in the following link:
www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windowsupdate/181710-re-error-number-80073712-a.html

i.e.

run a command prompt with "Run as Administrator".

Type in the following commands:

```
takeown /f C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml

cacls C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml /G <YourUsername>:F
```

I was then able to copy pending.xml off as a backup.

then I deleted the file.

I ran checkdisk and returned the hard disc to it’s computer.
This time on boot Vista did not get stuck on the endless reboot cycle.

Comment: You could change the file without fiddling with hardware by booting an Ubuntu or other LiveCD.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of removing the pending.xml from c:\windows\winsxs is a great idea but also you should move/delete any other files in that folder starting with pending.xml. and allow Windows update to build a fresh new update check, the first check takes a while but usually carries on from where the updates got up to without problems.

In my case I used Hirens Boot CD to boot the Mini Windows XP to allow me to access c:\windows\winsxs

Made a folder in the root called c:\pendings and moved all files starting with pending.xml to that folder, if you are a DOS box fan then the following is a nice fast repair...

Assuming C: is where your windows folder resides...

md c:\pendings

move c:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml*.* c:\pendings

shutdown -r -t 0

Answer (score 0):

*Unfortunately you have to get the CD /DVD from Some where and you can resolve this issue*

Depending on your version place any 32 or 64 bit VISTA dvd in your computer and reboot it.

Boot from the DVD ROM

Select restore from a previous restore point

The first two restore points available to me failed.  i had to go back 3 days before i found one that worked for me.

After that, manually attempt to download and install the update that was giving you issue.  i simply disabled automatic updates until i can find out more about why this even happened.

Source :http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/itprovistasp/thread/31ca7aee-2c6c-400c-aeee-bb00286d192a/

Might be these links useful for you :
http://www.ditii.com/2008/02/18/how-to-get-windows-vista-sp1-out-of-configuring-updates-stage-3-of-3-0-infinite-loop/

http://support.microsoft.com/support/kb/articles/q304/4/49.asp

Comment: Question clearly states that he does not have the disk

Comment: Answer clearly states he has to get the disk from "somewhere"

Answer (score 0):

Please use this solution that I have placed  on this forum.

Please follow exactly these steps then you computer should be working again.

I have used the following solution.
Restart computer.press f8 then choose option restore computer.
choose option open command.
type: prompt winsxs (press enter)
type: move C:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml text.xml (press enter)
type: exit and restart computer.
Computer should be working again.

good luck.
hope it works for you.
pieter.